# Create dynamic menu Windev with buttons

Tags: desktop, windev

I'm working in windev and I made a dynamic Menu using the menu control from information in my anylisis, now I'm trying to achieve the same using buttons in a ribbon, or just buttons but got stuck when creating the submenus for these buttons.

Answer (score 0):

In the description of a button you can attach a menu to it. You can always edit the menu dynamically. Is it what you're looking for ?

[Attach a menu to a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWLna.png)

Comment: Well, I need to attach that menu by programming, and I believe I can't use control clone or control create to a PopUp (which is the control that menus use to be build)